# Vaadin 8 with Vaadin 7 compatibility package: Sass compiler fails

Tags: java, maven, vaadin

I was working on a project which is using Vaadin7. I converted the project from vaadin 7 to vaadin 8 using **compatibility** in pom. I resolved all the dependencies required for this vaadin migration but when I build the project it's throwing com.vaadin.sass.SassCompiler error.

previous pom environment:-

```
    <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
                <version>7.5.10</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
                <version>7.5.10</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
                <version>7.5.10</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
     </dependency>
```

Current pom environment:-

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-compatibility-client</artifactId>
            <version>8.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
            <version>8.7.0</version>
            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-compatibility-client-compiled</artifactId>
            <version>8.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
            <version>8.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-compatibility-shared</artifactId>
            <version>8.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-shared</artifactId>
            <version>8.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-compatibility-themes</artifactId>
            <version>8.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
            <version>8.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-compatibility-server</artifactId>
            <version>8.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
            <version>8.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Plugin environment:-

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs> -->
                    <module>com.project.widgetsets.ProjectWidgetSet</module>
                    <webappDirectory>target/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets</webappDirectory>
                    <hostedWebapp>target/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets</hostedWebapp>
                    <noServer>true</noServer>
                    <compileReport>true</compileReport>
                    <style>OBF</style>
                    <strict>true</strict>
                    <runTarget>http://127.0.0.1:8080/</runTarget>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration></configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                            <goal>update-theme</goal>
                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                            <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I try to build the project using **mvn install** command it is giving me following error:-

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 53.367 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-04-15T18:41:04+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/46M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:8.7.0:compile-theme (default) on project jtservices: Compiling theme "VAADIN\themes\jt-theme" failed: Command [[
[ERROR] C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\bin\java -Xmx1G com.vaadin.sass.SassCompiler C:\Users\swaga\git\ng\jtb2b\protocols\src\main\resources\VAADIN\themes\jt-theme\styles.scss C:\Users\swaga\git\ng\jtb2b\protocols\src\main\resources\VAADIN\themes\jt-theme\styles.css
[ERROR] ]] failed with status 1
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: You should do as the output suggests: `To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.`

Comment: Yes, I already tried the maven command with -e switch but it's giving me same error of SassCompiler

Comment: I am not sure, if it affects anything, but  if you are using `vaadin-compatibility-server`, for example, remove `vaadin-server`. It might interfere with things. I see this for `client` package, so try to remove `vaadin-client` and build with `mvn clean install`. Especially with themes module, as I see now. Remove the `vaadin-themes`, if you have `compatibility-theme`. Also, what is your current theme?

Comment: Also, the similar issue reported here was resolved by removing explicitly from local maven repo the `themes` jar [Valo trouble after update to 8.1.1](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/16515804/valo-trouble-after-update-to-8-1-1) (But try to remove redundant dependencies first)

Comment: Have you customised the theme? it might be easier to create a new theme.

Comment: Title is vague. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Maybe you're using variables in your SASS files that were removed in v8?